# Alternating row colors in tabular(*|x)?

Tags: latex

I’m trying to create a table in my document that resembles more or less the table in the picture below:

[image: Example table with alternate row coloring]

This table is supposed to be stretched horizontally to `\textwidth`. My first attempt with `tabular*` looked like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tableShade}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
  \rowcolors{3}{tableShade}{white}  %% start alternating shades from 3rd row
  \noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lrrr}
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
  \end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

The result was:

[image: Example table with tabular*]

Well, the alternate row coloring works but `tabular*` inserts space between columns to stretch the whole table to `\textwidth`. Browsing through my LaTeX companion I found that `tabularx` should be able to do what I want. So I changed my code to look like that:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\definecolor{tableShade}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
  \rowcolors{3}{tableShade}{white}  %% start alternating shades from 3rd row
  \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xrrr}
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Now, this looks more like it. But `tabularx` ignores the starting row for the coloring and starts with the first row.

[image: Example table with tabularx]

Now I’ve run out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, such things are no longer a problem with the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={XXXX},
  row{odd}={bg=lightgray},  
  row{1}={bg=black,fg=white},
}
  Something & foo & bar & baz \\
  Something & foo & bar & baz \\
  Something & foo & bar & baz \\
  Something & foo & bar & baz \\
  Something & foo & bar & baz \\
\end{tblr}  
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Not a fix but a hack around, add \hiderowcolors to the first row, then turn colors back on with \showrowcolors.  See code:

```
\rowcolors{3}{tableShade}{white}  %% start alternating shades from 3rd row
  \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X X}%this can be {Xrrr} too
    \hiderowcolors 
     Something & foo & bar & baz \\
    \showrowcolors 
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
    Something & foo & bar & baz \\
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: I guess this is the best we can do currently without writing a a replacement for tabularx.